# Is there a divergent sequence such that for every n in N it is possible to find n consecutive ones somewhere in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was asked to create, if possible, a divergent sequence such that for every 
$n$ in $N$,  it is possible to find '$n$' consecutive ones somewhere in the sequence.

I came up with the sequence: $\{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,...\}$.

Where the series can be thought of in blocks. I.e, in block $n=1$ $\{1\}$, in block $n=2$, $\{1,1,2,2\}$ and so on.

I am wondering if there is a way to write this sequence in a more succinct way.

Comment: Probably. Or use another sequence, such as $a_n=1$ if $n$ is not a perfect square, and $a_n=n$ if $n$ is a perfect square.